# Why is wifi log filling with Usb Host Notification messages?

Tags: wifi, logs

A backup external hard drive (WD G Drive) is attached via USB. When I detach it, the messages below stop. When I reattach it, the messages don't continue.

I was casually checking logs on a Mac with Big Sur when I saw this.

Why might the /var/log/wifi.log be filled like so?

```
Sun Aug 22 00:45:12.451 Usb Host Notification en1 driver available, seqNum 52, Total 1  
Sun Aug 22 00:45:12.451 Usb Host Notification Error Apple80211Set:
:  
Sun Aug 22 01:16:57.517 Usb Host Notification en1 driver available, seqNum 58, Total 1
```

It has been doing this since the rotating log started (August 12). Yesterday I deleted the `WiFi` network connection from the Network system settings. But the messages keep repeating until I detached the hard drive.

It seems as if the external harddrive has something to do with the wifi log...